# Continue Azure Pipeline on failed task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a task that runs Cypress:

```
-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/
npx cypress run
```

And I've set the `ErrorActionPreference` to `continue`. But when my Cypress fails:

```
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

The next task is canceled and the release failed. How do I continue the release even Cypress failed, and is it possible to give a boolean a true/false value based on the Cypress task result?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you want to continue the release even the Cypress task failed, just add to the Cypress task this line:

```
continueOnError: true
```

Answer (score 33):

you can put a condition on the subsequent tasks to work even if previous tasks failed.

```
jobs:
- job: Foo

  steps:
  - powershell: |
      your code here
  - script: echo Hello!
    condition: always() # this step will always run, even if the pipeline is cancelled

- job: Bar
  dependsOn: Foo
  condition: failed() # this job will only run if Foo fails
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-status-functions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 14):

The argument "ErrorActionPreference" is used to setting whether the code inside this script execute with errors or not, it can’t control the next task.

You can add a condition in the end of the subsequent tasks.

`condition: always() # this step will always run, even if the pipeline is cancelled`

Or you can add an argument setting to the error task.

`continueOnError: true # 'true' if future steps should run even if this step fails; defaults to 'false'`

Hope this can help you!

Answer (score 8):

The **ErrorActionPreference** option is used to determine whether to continue to execute the rest of the code instead of another task. So, with continue **value** for **ErrorActionPreference**, the task will execute the next line of code of your script even through the current line throws an error, unless you call **exit** explicitly.

For your requirement, you are using a release pipeline (using the UI designer) and you want to continue to run the whole release, so, you just need to check the 'Continue on Error' option:

[image]

Comment: what we should use in ErrorActionPreference .: stop or continue ..? it i select  stop my task partially successed and it skip my next task which is for bug creation logic and the final stage my release is success.